# React app build folder and index.html blank

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I have finished my react app and created a build for it and got the build folder, when I go to open index.html the page that opens is blank. I am not looking to publish my website or do any back end I just want to have the front end working and make sure that its visible and be able to show it to someone on another machine without having them to download Node.js or anything like that.

I would like to be able to share my front end application to someone with everything on it working without having to make them download any packages.

I tried opening index.html after creating the build folder but it is blank. I have also tried adding a readme with my project but the steps are too long and require whoever is receiving it to download Node.js and add PATH environment variables which I don't want to happen.

Comment: When you say "blank" do you mean it has no text content whatsoever, or do you mean there's no HTML in the body except `<div id="root"></div>`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.